# SqlDataReader Close error

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

```
public static void DropDownList_Bind(DropDownList list_name,string DtaTxtField,string DataValueField,String Procedure)
   {
       OpenConnection();
       com = new SqlCommand(Procedure, con); 
       com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       SqlDataReader dtr = com.ExecuteReader();
       list_name.DataSource = dtr;
       list_name.DataTextField = DtaTxtField;
       list_name.DataValueField = DataValueField;
       list_name.DataBind();
       dtr.Close();
       CloseConnection();
   }
public static void OpenConnection()
    {
        if(con.State==ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();

    }
    public static void CloseConnection()
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();
    }
```

This is my Bussiness logic code for binding DropDownList,it is giving an execption *There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.* on `SqlDataReader dtr = com.ExecuteReader();` .please give some suggestions.
Thanx in advance

Comment: Can you show me code for `OpenConnection()` and `CloseConnectin()` ?

Comment: In first time ,has your data binding complete successfully ?

Comment: Yes ,first time it is binding succesfully .

Comment: has `CloseConnection()` fired ?

Comment: Do you have other code that is reading data from the database and running this code inside that? For example `using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteQuery()) { while (rdr.Read()) { DropDownList_Bind(rdr[0], rdr[1], rdr[2]); } }`

Comment: This is my bussiness logic code and i am binding two drpdownlist with same function on pageload
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                //DropDownList Binding through bussiness logic
                Bussiness_logic.DropDownList_Bind(DDL_U, "SHORT_DESC", "UNIT_CODE", "UNIT_SOURCE");
                Bussiness_logic.DropDownList_Bind(DDL_Branch, "TYPE_DESC", "TYPE_CODE", "BRANCH_SOURCE");
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make “MultipleActiveResultSets=True” in your connection string.

I have written a blog post at following link.

http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2013/06/Entity-Framework-There-is-already-an-open-DataReader-associated-with-this-Command.html

Regards,